# Accessing JSON array within Laravel Controller

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am currently a bit stuck with some data that my Vue component is sending to my Laravel Controller. The data is as follows:

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#1246
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "Developer"
  }
  1 => {#1249
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "Ops Matrix Admin"
  }
]
```

For example if I wanted to get the `name` or the `id` out of this as an object so that I can use it with eloquent. How would I go about doing this?

This is what my controller currently looks like.

```
  public function editUserPermissions(Request $request, $id) {
      foreach($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        $decode = json_decode($value);

        dd($decode);
    }
  }
```

When I do `dd($request->all());` I get the following:

```
array:1 [
  "body" => "[{"id":1,"name":"Developer"},{"id":3,"name":"Ops Matrix User"}]"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the result. The result is an array.

A better way to get this would be with $request->getContent()

But using your code

```
public function editUserPermissions(Request $request, $id) {
      foreach($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        $decode = json_decode($value);

        foreach($decode as $decoded) {
            echo $decoded['id'];
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. Currently I have already used ```json_decode``` and that is how I retrieved the dataset that I have put in my question. I do apologise if I was not clear. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi thank you. I have updated my question. Again apologies if I am being completely stupid. This problem has consumed me for about 2 days now :D

Comment: Hmmm I seem to be getting an error "```{message: "Undefined index: id", exception: "ErrorException",…}```" I feel really bad because I should of figured this one out.

Comment: Answer updated to include your updated code. I am assuming the first bit is dd($decode)

Comment: Thank you so much... Seriously, I have been banging my head off of a wall for a while. This has really helped. I now just need to make it comma separated, but I will check on that. You have done more than enough!

Comment: No problem. Take a look here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp for more information.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I can't seem to figure this out from a Laravel perspective.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function editUserPermissions(Request $request, $id) {
      $bodys = $request->body;
      foreach($bodys as $key => $body) {
           //$key give current index of array 
           $body[$key]['id'] //this give id 
           $body[$key]['name'] //this give name 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi :D With this solution to my problem I received the following error: ```{message: "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given", exception: "ErrorException",…}```

Comment: I have updated my question with the output from ```dd($request->all());```

Comment: $request->all() should be in there my fault.sorry

Comment: Ahh I see. New error for our pleasure. Sorry for bothering you with this. I really do appreciate the help. ```{message: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array", exception: "Error",…}```